# Append new content to existing content

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to append some content inside wordpress that needs to be attached by hooking it to 'the_content'. The new content appears fine along side what is existing, however it appears before the text instead of after it. 
Here is my code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'save_content',10);
add_filter('the_content', 'include_acf',20);
add_filter('the_content', 'append_content',30);

function save_content($saved_content){
  global $saved_content;
  $saved_content = get_the_content();
  return $saved_content;
}

function append_content ($saved_content) {
  $content = $saved_content . get_the_content();
  return $content;
}
```

*edit: changed add_action to filters and renamed functions*

Comment: have your tried  get_the_content().$saved_content

Comment: Why are you using `global $saved_content` when you're also passing that variable as an argument?

Comment: @PawneshKumar yeah it just has the same outcome

Comment: I am confused on the purpouse of save_content, is this relivent to the problem of yours?

Plus all you have to do is 

function append_content ($saved_content) {
  $content = get_the_content() .'Modify content';
  return $content;
}

Comment: pus you don't have to edit your original answer to show what you are trying latest. Just keep original and add edited version in next para.

Answer (score 0):

`add_filter` is correct hook to call on content so please use below code.but make sure that you are getting content in `get_the_content()` and also getting ACF content in `$saved_content`.

First try to print both then it will sure work

```
add_filter('the_content', 'save_content',10);
add_filter('the_content', 'append_acf',20);
function save_content($saved_content){
  global $saved_content;
  $saved_content = get_the_content();
  return $saved_content;
}


function append_acf ($saved_content) {
  $content = $saved_content . get_the_content();
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post to use filters and I've changed the function names because they were named poorly. However using what you've given me this still doesn't work sorry.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly needs to be changed, and why such changes are needed? What is wrong with the code from the question? Please add such explanations to your answer, such that others can learn from it